# Text Area of Pastebin

Tags: c#, webclient, pastebin

Hey I was just wondering how to can get just the text area of a Pastebin because i downloaded the Pastebin with a Webclient but i got all of this:

I just want the part that says Email, James, Gmail, etc

C# btw

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmx4I.png)

Any help would be great! Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) --> "Code or sample data in images can't be copied and pasted into an editor and compiled in order to reproduce the problem."